# Vue-CLI: Remove '.umd' from filename in dist folder

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-4

I'm generating a library with Vue CLI 4.4:

`vue-cli-service build --target lib --formats=umd,umd-min --name example main.js`

As a result, I get a number of files in the dist folder:

- `example.umd.js`
- `example.umd.min.js`
- ...

I'd like to remove the `.umd` from the file name. How to accomplish that?

I've tried the following two things in my `vue.config.js`, but it did not help:

```
    configureWebpack: {
        output: {
            filename: 'example.js',
            chunkFilename: 'example.[name].js'
        }
    }
```

```
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.output.filename('example.js')
        config.output.chunkFilename('example.[name].js')
    }
```

It seems vue-cli sets this "postfix" here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/commands/build/resolveLibConfig.js#L140
Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to override it without forking the whole project.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.